# Subtracting time.Duration from time in Go

Tags: datetime, go

I have a `time.Time` value obtained from `time.Now()` and I want to get another time which is exactly 1 month ago.

I know subtracting is possible with `time.Sub()` (which wants another `time.Time`), but that will result in a `time.Duration` and I need it the other way around.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Try [AddDate](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()

    fmt.Println("now:", now)

    then := now.AddDate(0, -1, 0)

    fmt.Println("then:", then)
}
```

Produces:

```
now: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
then: 2009-10-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/QChq02kisT

Comment: what about subtracting a time?

Comment: Subtracting **a time** and subtracting **time** are different operations.  To subtract **a time**, you would call time.Now().Sub(time.Time{}) to get the difference as a Duration.  To subtract **an amount of time**, say 1 minute, you'd have to do time.Now().Add(**time.Minute * -1**). The lack of symmetry between Sub() and Add() is infuriating.

Comment: Diff() or such would have been a much more intuitive alternative for calculating duration than the current Add/Sub confusion...

Answer (score 223):

In response to Thomas Browne's comment, because [lnmx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285835/55504) only works for subtracting a date, here is a modification of his code that works for subtracting time from a time.Time type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()

    fmt.Println("now:", now)

    count := 10
    then := now.Add(time.Duration(-count) * time.Minute)
    // if we had fix number of units to subtract, we can use following line instead fo above 2 lines. It does type convertion automatically.
    // then := now.Add(-10 * time.Minute)
    fmt.Println("10 minutes ago:", then)
}
```

Produces:

```
now: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
10 minutes ago: 2009-11-10 22:50:00 +0000 UTC
```

Not to mention, you can also use `time.Hour` or `time.Second` instead of `time.Minute` as per your needs.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DzzH4SA3izp

Comment: Don't user `ParseDuration` for static values! Just use `-10 * time.Minute`, that's what those constants are defined for. E.g. just `time.Now().Add(-10 * time.Minute)` is all you would need.

Comment: Wow, the time API is so inconsistent. time.Add is to add a duration, while time.Sub is to substract a time. Glad I found this answer because I was looking at the Sub function and I would never have guessed it has a different signature from Add.

Comment: Also note that go implicitly converts `now.Add(-10 * time.Minute)` to `now.Add(time.Duration(-10) * time.Minute)` in case your getting an error when multiplying a duration by an int value...

Answer (score 78):

You can negate a `time.Duration`:

```
then := now.Add(- dur)
```

You can even compare a `time.Duration` against `0`:

```
if dur > 0 {
    dur = - dur
}

then := now.Add(dur)
```

You can see a working example at http://play.golang.org/p/ml7svlL4eW

Comment: There's a catch though: `-1 * dur` will work, but `d := -1 ; dur = d * dur` will generate an error: "mismatched types int and time.Duration"

Comment: That is the right answer for the question's title and it should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's `time.ParseDuration` which will happily accept negative durations, [as per manual](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseDuration). Otherwise put, there's no need to negate a duration where you can get an exact duration in the first place.

E.g. when you need to substract an hour and a half, you can do that like so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()

    fmt.Println("now:", now)

    duration, _ := time.ParseDuration("-1.5h")

    then := now.Add(duration)

    fmt.Println("then:", then)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/63p-T9uFcZo